# VB Get object name

Tags: vb.net, object, properties

I'm working on a Visual Basic project and i ran into a problem.
I created 81 labels (By hand, Without an array) and i need to give them code.
I want to accses that label's properties, such as Name and Text; But i don't want to change the code for each one
Can i do something like: `this.Name` to get the name of the current label? Even my teacher dosen't know how to solve that.
I tried `Me.name` but that returns the name of the form... and I can't find any documentation anywhere.
Please help soon, Sagi.

Comment: No code, just labels. Not even an array as well.

Comment: what is a "current label"?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the name of the label when the label is clicked, you can use the `sender` argument of the Click event. For example here is a method that handles the Click event of two labels.

```
Sub Label_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click, Label2.Click
    Dim thisLabel As Label = CType(sender, Label)
    Dim myName As String = thisLabel.Name 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have an issue about a control, you should look it up on MSDN first. If you look up label, you can see that Name is indeed a property. See here: 
[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This.name will return the form control. You have to find the label's individual control and get the name that way. Like, "Label1.Name".

Comment: Calling `ToString` on `Label1.Name` is redundant.  `Label1.Name` is already a string.

Comment: It's not specificly on labels; I just need to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the controls on the form to get their properties.  Something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each lbl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
        MessageBox.Show(lbl.Name)
        MessageBox.Show(lbl.Text)
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Blackwood's answer above is what you need.  You just need to either use a `Handles` clause for each label or use `AddHandler` and a loop, using similar code to what I have above:

```
Private Sub wireUpLabelEvents()
    'Get each label on the form and wire up the event handler
    For Each lbl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
        AddHandler lbl.Click, AddressOf Label_Click
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Label_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    Dim thisLabel As Label = CType(sender, Label)
    Dim myName As String = thisLabel.Name 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx, But i want this code to activate on a click event

Comment: That IS a click event handler.  @Chris Dunaway literally just handed you the answer on a silver platter and you didn't even realize it.  Wow.

Comment: I meant when you click the label... Sorry maybe i was being too obscure.

Comment: @sageek - In that case, what Blackwook posted above is what you want.  You will have to either use a bunch of  `Handles` clauses at the end of the click event or use the `AddHandler` method to wire up the events for all the labels.